# Computing a similarity score for a set of sentences

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

My team does a lot of chatbot training, and I'm trying to come up with some tools to improve the quality of our work.  In chatbot training, it is really important to train intents with diverse utterances that phrase the same intent in very different ways.  Ideally, there would be very little similarity in the syntax of the utterances in the set.

**Here's an example for an intent inquiring about medical insurance coverage**

*Bad set of utterances*

- Is my daughter covered by insurance?
- Is my son covered by medical insurance?
- Will my son be covered by insurance?

*Decent set of utterances*

- How can I look up whether we have insurance coverage for the whole family?
- Seeking details on eligibility for medical coverage
- Is there a document that details who is protected under our medical insurance policy?

I want to be able to take all of the utterances associated to an intent and analyze them for similarity.  I would expect my set of bad utterances to have a high similarity score and my set of decent utterances to have a low similarity score.

I've tried playing around with a few doc2vec tutorials, but I feel like I'm missing something.  I keep seeing stuff like this:

- Train a set of data and then measure the similarity of a new sentence to your set of data
- Measure the similarity between two sentences

I need to have an array of sentences and understand how similar they are to each other.

Any advice on achieving this?

Answering some questions:

1. What makes the bad utterances bad?The utterances themselves are not bad, it is the lack of variety between them. If most of the training had been like the “bad” set, then real user utterances of greater variety will not be recognized correctly.
2. Are you trying to discover new intents? No, this is for prerelease training, trying to improve the effectiveness of it.
3. Why do bad utterances have high similarity scores and decent utterances have low similarity scores?  This is a hypothesis. I know how varied real user utterances are, and I have found my trainers fall into ruts when training, asking things the same way, and not seeing good accuracy results. Improving the variety in the utterances tends to result in better accuracy.
4. What will I do with this info? I’ll use it to assess the training quality of an intent, to determine if more training is likely necessary. In the future we might build real time tools as utterances are being added to let trainers know if they’re being too repetitive.

Comment: Can you clarify in the question: (1) what makes the "bad utterances" bad?; (2) Are all utterances already associated with an intent, or are you trying to discover new intents and/or associate new utterances with prior intents?; (3) Why would you expect "bad" utterances to have high-similarity (with each other?) but "decent" utterances to have low-similarity scores? (4) What's the ultimate goal – what do you intend to do with the sim scores? If a pair of sentences (or all pairs within a group) have "high sim" or "low sim", what will you do with that info? Discard some sentences?

Comment: Great questions. I’ll put answers in original question

Comment: @gojomo let me know if the edits I made answer your question

Comment: That's helpful... so it seems the real goal is to identify when these sentences, meant as training inputs for some *other* process/algorithm, have a good amount of superficial variety? And thus, give feedback to some human trainers that prompts them into generating better (more varied) examples?

Comment: @gojomo that’s correct

Answer (score 0):

Most applications of text vectors benefit from the vectors capturing the "essential meaning" of a text, **without* regard to variances in word choice.

That is, it's considered a feature, not a flaw, if two completely different wordings with similar meaning have nearly the same vector. (Or, if some similarity-measure indicates they are totally similar.)

For example, to contrive an example similar to yours, consider the two phrasings:

"health coverage for brother"
"male sibling medical insurance"

There's no reuse of words, but the likely intended meaning is the same – so a good text-vectorization for typical purposes would create very similar vectors. And a similarity-measure using those vectors, or otherwise using the words/word-vectors as input, would indicate very high similarity.

But from your clarifying answers, it seems you actually want a more superficial "similarity" measure. You'd like a measure that reveals when certain phrasings show variety/contrast in their wording. (And specifically, you already know form other factors, like how they were hand-crafted, that groups of these phrasings are semantically related.)

What you want this similarity measure to show is actually a behavior that many projects using text-vectors would consider a failure of the vectors. So semantic methods like those in Word2Vec, Paragraph Vectors (aka "Doc2Vec"), etc are likely the wrong tool for your goal.

You could probably do well with a simpler measure based just on the words, or perhaps character-n-grams, of the texts.

For example, for two texts A and B, you could just tally the number of shared words (that appear in both A and B), and divide by the total number of unique words in both A and B, to get a 0.0 to 1.0 "word choice similarity" number.

And, when considering a new text against a set of prior texts, if its average similarity to the prior texts is low, it'd be "good" for your purposes.

Rather than just words, you could also use all n-character substrings ("n-grams") of your texts – which might help better highlight differences in word-forms, or common typos, which may also be useful variances for your purposes.

In general, I'd look at the scikit-learn text-vectorization functionality for ideas:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction